# why merge statement is much slower in partitioned table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a big table (14million records) and I will need to apply merge statements (basically need to update/insert/delete some data). As the table is quite big, this has been my strategy:

```
insert into #ProjectUnitsCacheDetailExisting([ProjectUnitsCacheId], UniverseCode,CitiCode)
    SELECT ProjectUnitsCacheId, UniverseCode,CitiCode
    FROM dbo.ProjectUnitsCacheDetail WHERE ProjectUnitsCacheId = @CacheID

;MERGE #ProjectUnitsCacheDetailExisting AS T
            USING @ProjectUnitsCacheDetail AS S
                        ON (t.UniverseCode = s.UniverseCode and t.CitiCode = s.CitiCode)
                WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
                        THEN 

INSERT(ActionType,ProjectUnitsCacheId,UniverseCode,CitiCode)
    VALUES('INSERT', @CacheId,s.UniverseCode,s.CitiCode)
insert into ProjectUnitsCacheDetail(
                    ProjectUnitsCacheId, UniverseCode,CitiCode)
                select @CacheId,UniverseCode,CitiCode
                from #ProjectUnitsCacheDetailExisting
                where actionType = 'INSERT'
```

Basically work out what needs to be added, updated and deleted in a temp table first, and then delete/add/update the data. This works much quicker than applying the merge statement directly on my 14 million record table.

I then learned about partitioned table, thought it could be a good usage for me. So I created a table that is partitioned by 10 (the partition key is ProjectUnitsCacheId % 10), then apply the merge statement directly on the new table. However, it becomes much slower.

```
;MERGE ProjectUnitsCacheDetailTest AS T
            USING @ProjectUnitsCacheDetail AS S
                        ON (t.UniverseCode = s.UniverseCode and t.CitiCode = s.CitiCode) AND T.ProjectUnitsCacheId=@CacheID
                WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
                        THEN INSERT (  ProjectUnitsCacheId,UniverseCode,CitiCode)values( @CacheId,s.UniverseCode,s.CitiCode)
                        ....delete action
                        ....update action
```

This method becomes 10 time slower than the temp table way. If I do a direct select with @CacheId as parameter, the partitioned table indeed returns data quicker. So what could be the problem?

Comment: IMO: Reading data from a partitioned table will be faster; writing to it will always be slower due to the overhead of determining which file each record has to be written to and the need to maintain the index data for each partition.  So depending on the # of indexes on on the table * number of indexes, alot more overhead maintenance has to occur in order to insert a single record.  This comes at a cost when doing updates inserts/deletes, but it makes reads really fast especially if limits are imposed along the partitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that now your table is partitioned, its content is split in different disk places and indexes. So unless the data you are comparing against is matched with 1 partition, operations such as updates, inserts or deletes will *most likely* be slower than it's full, non-partitioned counter part.

Partitioned tables are good for querying data by it's partition column and operating with 1 partition at a time. If you tend to do operations among all the partitions maybe you want to review the partition key, or consider not having the table partitioned.

Comment: but I have ProjectUnitsCacheId = @CacheID in the merge statement, shouldn't that limit the partition to 1 as the partition key is based on the cache id (basically ProjectUnitsCacheId % 10)?

Comment: The `MERGE` might act as a full join if you use the clause `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE`. This might force the engine to look at other partitions outside the matching set. Also you can join against a particular `ProjectUnitsCacheId` but insert the record with another value for this key (you have `values(@CacheId, ...` but seems that the engine doesn't realize).